# SQL MAX Aggregate VS. Manual Calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I noticed something in our production code and it really threw me off. We have a data table that has the year that someone was in contact with us. Lets say it goes back to the late 90s.

We have a query that calculates the previous year to use in other future calculations within the same query. It looks like this:

```
@CurrYear = 2016

select  @PrevYear = max(Year)
from    x
where   x.Year < @CurrYear
```

This seems like a very convoluted way...not sure why this person didnt do:

```
@PrevYear = @CurrYear - 1
```

I'm asking this more in a query performance standpoint. Which is faster? Why so much code to calculate previous year?

Comment: You can quickly find out which is faster by running both.

Comment: The author did did not use `@PrevYear = @CurrYear - 1` because the author believed -- correctly or incorrectly -- that some years might be missing.

Comment: The query is pulling the previous year *that had data*.  Sure, you can just subtract 1 from the current year, but I suppose the intent was to pull the previous year that had data attached to it.  Without seeing the data, that's really all I can say.  `Which is faster?` - subtracting 1.  `Which is correct?` - I don't know, depends on what it's being used for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Thank you everyone...I thought this person was making unnecessary extra work for the DB, BUT in a few rare cases we can have an entire year missing for one of our contacts. Very forward thinking, whoever wrote this for us.

Answer (score 3):

I believe he either didn't think of another way to do it, or he wanted `@PrevYear` to represent the last year that you'd been contacted (Lets say there is no data from 2015, then `@PrevYear` should be 2014 .

In terms of performance, your suggestion should be faster as it is a calculation on parameters. It's hard to say if there will be any difference between them, depends on the size of the table, indexes and etc.

Comment: Thank you, sagi. I wrote a comment above. In a few rare cases we can be missing a year. Very forward thinking by our IT department.